# Why select is so ugly ? Can I customize it?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've been satisfied using Ionic but now when I've tried to use select element, it has a very strange appearence, at least on Android devices. It looks like this:

[image]

It's very ugly! There is a way to customize this appearence, or implement another thing instead of select, which is more beautiful?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @vinicus please check [this](http://play.ionic.io/app/770b70ac2408)

Comment: Thanks @Webruster, that's gonna be the way :)

Comment: @vinicus i posted this as answer please  mark it as answer for future users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your Reference  See this [Link](http://play.ionic.io/app/770b70ac2408) ,and also pasting the code incase for Future Users.
**HTMl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ionicApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <script id="templates/event-menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

        <ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
              <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
              </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
          </ion-nav-bar>

          <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content> 

        <ion-side-menu side="left">
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>

      </ion-side-menus>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Directive to Select multiple options">
        <ion-content scroll="false">
          <ion-multiple-select title="Select Users" options="users" key-property="id" value-property="name" selected-property="selected" class="item item-input item-icon-right">
            <div class="input-label">
              User
            </div>
            <i class="icon ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i>
          </ion-multiple-select>
          <textarea class="padding" disabled="disabled">{{ getOptionsSelected(users, 'name', 'selected') }}</textarea>
          <ion-multiple-select title="Select Groups" template-url="templates/multipleSelect.html" options="groups" key-property="Id" value-property="Name" selected-property="Selected" class="item item-input item-icon-right" render-checkbox="false" animation="slide-in-left">
            <div class="input-label">
              Group
            </div>
            <i class="icon ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i>
          </ion-multiple-select>
          <textarea class="padding" disabled="disabled">{{ getOptionsSelected(groups, 'Name', 'Selected') }}</textarea>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
    <script id="templates/multipleSelect.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view>
        <ion-header-bar align-title="center">
            <button class="button button-clear button-icon ion-close" ng-click="closeModal();"></button>
            <h1 class="title">{{multipleSelect.title}}</h1>
            <button class="button button-clear button-icon ion-checkmark" ng-click="saveOptions();"></button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content scroll="false">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="item item-toggle" ng-repeat="option in multipleSelect.tempOptions" ng-if="!multipleSelect.renderCheckbox">
                    {{ option[multipleSelect.valueProperty] }}
                    <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option[multipleSelect.selectedProperty]">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat="option in multipleSelect.tempOptions" ng-if="multipleSelect.renderCheckbox">
                   <label class="checkbox">
                     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option[multipleSelect.selectedProperty]">
                   </label>
                   {{ option[multipleSelect.valueProperty] }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}

textarea{
  width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    border: 3px solid #cccccc !important;
}

.slide-in-left {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0); }

.slide-in-left.ng-enter, .slide-in-left > .ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 1) 400ms;
  -moz-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 1) 400ms;
  -o-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 1) 400ms;
  -ms-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 1) 400ms;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 1) 400ms; 
}

.slide-in-left.ng-enter-active, .slide-in-left > .ng-enter-active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }

.slide-in-left.ng-leave, .slide-in-left > .ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  -o-transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  -ms-transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms; 
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('eventmenu', {
      url: "/event",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/event-menu.html"
    })
    .state('eventmenu.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
        }
      }
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event/home");
})
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $filter) { 

  $scope.users = [
    {id: 1, name: "Valentina", selected: true},
    {id: 2, name: "Juan David", selected: false},
    {id: 3, name: "Osman", selected: false},
    {id: 4, name: "Silva", selected: false}
  ];

  $scope.groups = [
    {Id: 1, Name: "Admin", Selected: false},
    {Id: 2, Name: "Developers", Selected: false},
    {Id: 3, Name: "Testers", Selected: false},
    {Id: 4, Name: "Users", Selected: false}
  ];

  $scope.getOptionsSelected = function(options, valueProperty, selectedProperty){
    var optionsSelected = $filter('filter')(options, function(option) {return option[selectedProperty] == true; });
    return optionsSelected.map(function(group){ return group[valueProperty]; }).join(", ");
  };
})
.directive('ionMultipleSelect', ['$ionicModal', '$ionicGesture', function ($ionicModal, $ionicGesture) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      options : "="
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.multipleSelect = {
        title:            $attrs.title || "Select Options",
        tempOptions:      [],
        keyProperty:      $attrs.keyProperty || "id",
        valueProperty:    $attrs.valueProperty || "value",
        selectedProperty: $attrs.selectedProperty || "selected",
        templateUrl:      $attrs.templateUrl || 'templates/multipleSelect.html',
        renderCheckbox:   $attrs.renderCheckbox ? $attrs.renderCheckbox == "true" : true,
        animation:        $attrs.animation || 'slide-in-up'
      };

      $scope.OpenModalFromTemplate = function (templateUrl) {
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(templateUrl, {
          scope: $scope,
          animation: $scope.multipleSelect.animation
        }).then(function (modal) {
          $scope.modal = modal;
          $scope.modal.show();
        });
      };

      $ionicGesture.on('tap', function (e) {
       $scope.multipleSelect.tempOptions = $scope.options.map(function(option){
         var tempOption = { };
         tempOption[$scope.multipleSelect.keyProperty] = option[$scope.multipleSelect.keyProperty];
         tempOption[$scope.multipleSelect.valueProperty] = option[$scope.multipleSelect.valueProperty];
         tempOption[$scope.multipleSelect.selectedProperty] = option[$scope.multipleSelect.selectedProperty];

         return tempOption;
       });
        $scope.OpenModalFromTemplate($scope.multipleSelect.templateUrl);
      }, $element);

      $scope.saveOptions = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.multipleSelect.tempOptions.length; i++){
          var tempOption = $scope.multipleSelect.tempOptions[i];
          for(var j = 0; j < $scope.options.length; j++){
            var option = $scope.options[j];
            if(tempOption[$scope.multipleSelect.keyProperty] == option[$scope.multipleSelect.keyProperty]){
              option[$scope.multipleSelect.selectedProperty] = tempOption[$scope.multipleSelect.selectedProperty];
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        $scope.closeModal();
      };

      $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
      };
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
          if ($scope.modal){
              $scope.modal.remove();
          }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```